# Java code for extraction of media information from XML

Tags: java, xml

I have the following XML.
I need to create a java servelet that will extract the media information from this XML.
How do i go about doing it. I am not interested in using any java libraries. Any manual way to do it without libraries?

My XML is the following

```
<result cover="http://ia.mediaimdb.com/images      
/M/MV5BMjMyOTM4MDMxNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjIyNzExOA@@._V1._SX54_
CR0,0,54,74_.jpg" title="The Amazing Spider-Man(2012)"year="2012"
director="Marc Webb" rating="7.5"
details="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0948470"/>

<result cover="http://ia.mediaimdb.
com/images/M/MV5BMzk3MTE5MDU5NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjY3NTY3._V1._SX54_CR0,
0,54,74_.jpg" title="Spider-Man(2002)" year="2002"director="Sam Raimi"
rating="7.3" details="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0145487"/>

<result cover="http://ia.mediaimdb.
com/images/M/MV5BODUwMDc5Mzc5M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDgzOTY0MQ@@._V1._SX54_
CR0,0,54,74_.jpg" title="Spider-Man 3 (2007)" year="2007" director="Sam
Raimi" rating="6.3" details="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0413300"/>

<result cover="http://i.mediaimdb.
com/images/SF1f0a42ee1aa08d477a576fbbf7562eed/realm/feature.gif" title="
The Amazing Spider-Man 2 (2014)" year="2014" director="Sam Raimi"
rating="6.3" details="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1872181"/>

<result cover="http://ia.mediaimdb.
com/images/M/MV5BMjE1ODcyODYxMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA1NDE3MQ@@._V1._SX54_
CR0,0,54,74_.jpg" title="Spider-Man 2 (2004)" year="2004" director="Sam
Raimi" rating="7.5" details="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0316654"/>
</results>
```

Comment: *"Any manual way to do it without libraries?"*  Sure.  Write code that does what the other APIs (you don't want to use) do.  Unless that is the answer, this is at risk of being 'not a real question'.  Or perhaps ***even if*** that is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You surely shouldn't try it "without any libraries". Libraries are your very best friends. Using libraries this can be few lines + a jar dependency..

Anyways: you have XPath at your hand to query for information from this document. You have dom4j, SAX, etc. You can also go with simple regular expressions, however this is not the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Using java libraries that will make your task straight forward.Simply Use digester.jar...:)